# Como colocar imagem em uma lista <thead>

Tags: html, html5

Sou iniciante em programação e estou montando uma lista utilizando `thead` e queria saber como posso colocar uma imagem dentro da `<th>`.

Meu código abaixo:

```
<thead>
     <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Rádio Vale FM</th>
         <th>04.362.624/0001-00</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

E como ele está aparecendo no site:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero colocar uma imagem ali onde está o `#`.  Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Assim `<th><img src="URL_DA_IMAGEM" /></th>` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: @NoobSaibot sim!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione a tag `<img src="minha-imagem.jpg" alt="texto-alternativo">` dentro de sua tag `<th>`

Lembre de adicionar o caminho completo até a pasta da sua imagem no atributo `src`

Comment: para que serve esse ''alt=''texto-alternativo''?

Comment: Navegadores nem sempre exibem a imagem referenciada pelo elemento. Este é o caso para navegadores não gráficos (incluindo aqueles usados por pessoas com deficiência de visão), ou se o usuário optar por não exibir imagens ou se o navegador não conseguir exibir a imagem porque é inválido ou um tipo não suportado. Nesses casos, o navegador pode substituir a imagem pelo texto definido no atributo alt  deste elemento.